# What does a negative value mean for a liability on the London Stock Exchange Fundamentals page?

Tags: stock-analysis

Take this page :

http://www.londonstockexchange.com/exchange/prices/stocks/summary/fundamentals.html?fourWayKey=GB00B1YMN108GBGBXASQ1

Under non-current liabilities

What does a negative value mean for borrowings?

Does that mean they started paying it back?  or is it what they borrowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what's owed.

You can follow the math by looking at current assets, current liabilities and net current assets.

```
Current Assets       1.47
Current Liabilities -0.54
                    ------
Net Current Assets   0.94
```

Obviously there's a little rounding error when you're only given 3 digits of a 7 digit number, but you get the picture.